# plotting means, errors, and then raw data in background - simpler code?

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot a the mean and standard error of a continuous variable, grouped by a categorical one in `R`. I then want in the background to have the actual raw data points that went in to generating that mean and standard error. The resulting plot will look like this:

[image]

I coded this myself, however it requires multiple custom functions (for generating standard error, group means), as well as adding some things to the data frame to generate the jitter and get around some graphics hiccups. The code is copied here and will generate all necessary data:

```
##generate some fake data###
ctrl<- rnorm(20,1,0.5)
treated<- rnorm(20,2,0.5)
ctrl.lab<- rep('ctrl',20)
treated.lab<- rep('treated',20)
#adding 1s and 2s that correspond to treatment for plotting later. The niormal distribution allows me to jitter the points along the y-axis
ctrl.alt<- rnorm(20,1,0.02) 
treated.alt<- rnorm(20,2,0.02)
alt<-c(ctrl.alt,treated.alt) later
lab<-c(ctrl.lab,treated.lab)
response<- c(ctrl,treated)

data<-data.frame(lab,response,alt)

#make a function for plotting error bars
errb <- function (x, y, ebl, ebu = ebl, length = 0.06, ...){
  arrows(x, y + ebu, x, y - ebl, angle = 90, code = 3,
  length = length, ...)
  }
#make a function that will grab a data frame, and kick back means and standard errors by a grouping variable. 
meanerr<- function(data,param,grouping){
    means<-aggregate(param~grouping,data=data,FUN=mean)
    sd<-aggregate(param~grouping,data=data,FUN=sd)
    count<-aggregate(param~grouping,data=data,FUN=length)
    err<-sd$param/sqrt(count$param)
    output<-cbind(means,err)
    return(output)
}  

d3<-meanerr(data,data$response,data$lab)
d3$alt<-c(1,2) #for plotting. 
limx<-c(0.6,2.4) #set x limits
limy<-c(0,3.1) #set y limits

#start with plotting the jittered raw data points. 
plot(data$alt,data$response,
    pch=16,
    xaxt='n',
    ylab=NA,
    xlab='',
    xlim=limx,
    ylim=limy,
    col='light gray')
par(new=T)
#now add the mean and standard error
plot(d3$alt,d3$param,
    pch=16,
    xaxt='n',
    ylab=NA,
    xlab='',
    cex=2,
    xlim=limx,
    ylim=limy,
    col='black')
    axis(1,at=1:2, labels=d3$grouping,cex.axis=1.4)
    mtext('response',2,cex=1,line=2)
    errb(d3$alt,d3$param,d3$err,col='black',cex=2)
```

This is a ton of code to make one figure! Is there a simpler way to do this- either without cstom functions, or using ggplot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with much less code in `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(lab, response)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.3, position=position_jitter(height=0, width=0.05)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=function(x){mean_cl_normal(x, conf.int=.683)}, geom="errorbar", 
               width=0.03, colour="red", alpha=0.7) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", fill="red", pch=21, size=3)
```

(Updated per @Roland's comment: One standard error is equivalent to a confidence interval of 68.3%.)

[image]

Comment: They want to plot the standard error. `mean.se <- function(x, ...) ggplot2:::mean_sdl(x, mult = 1/sqrt(length(x)), ...)` could be used for this.

Comment: Thanks Roland. I've updated my answer. Since 1 se is equivalent to a CI of 68.2%, I've just used `mean_cl_normal` with a 1 se confidence level.